# Windows fails to resume from hibernation every other reboot

Tags: windows, hibernate

I have a Dell XPS 15z. Under Windows 7, I was seeing the problem where Windows wouldn't resume from hibernation on every other reboot. In other words, I could cold boot, and it would hibernate and resume correctly multiple times. If I then did a Restart, when it tried to next resume from hibernate, it would fail, and do a cold restart, and then hibernate would work find again. There is nothing useful in the event log - all it says is that the last shutdown's success was set to false, and then it says "Windows failed to resume from hibernate with error status 0xc0000411".

I'm now getting the same problem on Windows 8.

Does anyone have any ideas? Is there any more logging or diagnostics I can turn on to find out more?

Comment: Did you updated the laptop BIOS to latest version?

Comment: Yes. It's all up to date, as are drivers.

Comment: I am sure I had this problem already, and I had to download a "restricted" hotfix (they emailed me the download link) that fixed it, but I don't remember what it was.

Comment: I have seen another Dell laptop with similar problem. It's problem was graphic driver. So your problem is seemingly related with drivers.

Comment: possible duplicate http://superuser.com/questions/884270/windows-sometimes-fails-to-resume-from-hibernate

Comment: Do I understand correctly that if you cold boot, it will hibernate and resume ok, but if you reboot, it then will not hibernate and resume from hibernation?

Are any peripherals (e.g. USB devices) changing between hibernation and resume? Is any other kind of system state changing between hibernation and resume?

I have found sometimes that Windows 7 will hang when attempting to resume from hibernation if, for example, I had a USB thumb drive connected when I hibernated, but removed the USB drive before attempting to resume from hibernation.

Comment: Citzenmatt - There may be other configuration issues that you may want to consider:  ***(A.)*** Is Windows using any drive for ReadyBoost?  ***(B.)*** Are ExpressCache, Diskeeper, or any other hard drive performance tools being used? ***(C.)*** Is the System partition, (or others), encrypted using Bitlocker, or other encryptions systems? ***(D.)*** Is your laptop running with an OEM provided power management utility? ***(E.)*** My guess is a "Hybrid Sleep" configuration issue, if it is configured this way, let me know and I will post an explanation.

Answer (score 2):

We have a lot of Dell computers (desktops and laptops both) that have this problem, with hibernate and sleep. For some, it was a graphics driver, for others it was a storage device driver. The installed driver wasn't necessarily the *wrong* one, but using a different version of the driver corrected the problem. Best of luck to you..

Answer (score 1):

To what was said above you need to check your hard drive for surface and file system errors. hiberfil.sys has a big size and can be often corrupted in case of bad sectors.

To check the file system use chkdsk: e.g. `chkdsk c: /f /r`
To check the HDD surface use tools like HDDScan or HDTune. They allow to read and verify the surface for bad or slowly-read sectors (that are close to become bad).

Answer (score 0):

Check your BIOS boot order.
Sometimes if set to boot from another device (i.e. USB, Network PXE, etc) before the local HDD I think it can somehow interfere with the cached hibernation file sometimes.
See if switching boot order to HDD first helps at all.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I would say your OS's files have become inconsistent. I recommend this simple command (in Command Prompt) to renew your system:

```
sfc /scannow
```

is all you need to initiate that repair function (that is a framework included in windows) and let it run. It may take a bit if your system has some holes. If you are curious to know other functions of this framework you can type `sfc /?` into Command Prompt.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

> 1) Disable Hibernation.  2) Delete the hiberfil.sys file. 3) Reboot
>   the computer and run 'Disk Cleanup.'  4) Defragment the drive. 5)
>   Reboot one more time.  6) Reenable Hibernation.

here info to delete the hibernation files.

> I’ve previously written a post explaining what the hiberfil.sys file
>   is and how you can remove it in Windows Vista. In Windows 7, you the
>   hibernation file can still take up a large amount of space on your
>   hard drive.
>
> In this post, we will show you how to delete the hiberfil.sys file and
>   how to turn off hibernation. You can free up a decent amount of space
>   by doing this.
>
> Delete Hiberfil.sys File To delete this file, you have to use the
>   command prompt to manually turn off hibernation. If you turn off
>   hibernation via Power Options (which I will show you next), it will
>   not delete the actual file itself.
>
> Open a command prompt in Windows 7 by typing command in the search
>   box. Right click Command Prompt and choose Run as Administrator.
>
> delete hiberfil sys
>
> To turn off or disable hibernation, type the following command at the
>   prompt:
>
> powercfg –h off

after that you should turn on again the hibernation

powercfg –h on

here some more info

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/windows-7-your-computer-cannot-come-out-of/20ffb7a3-7f0c-46f9-8516-c1e31b11e558?auth=1

http://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-7/windows-7-delete-hibernation-file-hiberfil-sys/

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately sleep and hibernation modes depend on many factors: how the hardware works, how the PC hardware systems interact with each other, how ugly the device drivers are written and in rare cases - which software did you run (yes, Windows isn't a 100% fortress and can make the PC to run wrong after some software has been started).

Usually problems arise in desktop PCs as they have components from different vendors. Laptops usually have finely tuned components that fit each other. But even there no guarantee could be given.

Here is my experience:

I encountered full Windows destruction after a PC went a couple of time to hibernate mode: some of drivers supposedly couldn't correctly recover their state that must correspond to current hardware state; memory had been corrupted and it affected in some way important system data. Then this data had been written to disk and Windows was finished.

One of laptops has been used in battery backed sleep mode. It was put in sleep mode for a couple times each day and finally Windows Vista began to encounter strange errors and worked decently only without paging file. The final moment of all this was that Windows initiated chkdsk and hung at every boot on phase 5. I replaced the HDD, cloned the system and everything repeated again: after a year the system went to unusable state.

My wife's laptop sometimes refuses to wake up from sleep. All it shows is a black screen and high fan speed.

There are plenty of problems related to sleep modes. On every PC it is a lottery with 40% of winning chance.

So my advise is to put up with it and disable the hibernation mode.

Answer (score 0):

There may be no solution for this issue, but I would try the following before giving up.

**1) BIOS side**

Install latest BIOS from the manufacturer's official website. (This may brick your device if anything goes wrong!)

Try to find settings for **ACPI S-states** in your BIOS, if there is any. Hibernation states are usually named S4, S5 or S6 or a section related to standby, hibernation or power.

Play with the settings, change only one setting at a time and try the hibernation.

For Sx power state details see this post: [ACPI System Level (Sx) states](http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=354552)

**2) OS side** - set values to 0 = disabled

Go to `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Power Options\Edit Plan Settings` and click `Change advanced power settings`
-`Sleep mode and Hibernate`
-`Hybrid sleep`
-`Turn off hard disk after`

**3) Sometimes there is no solution**

I had a similar experience recently with Lenovo enterprise/milspec category notebooks.

1. Latest drivers
2. Windows updated
3. BIOS/UEFI settings checked
4. OS energy management settings OK

**4) Try Linux instead of Windows?**

I hope this can help :)

Answer (score 0):

A faulty optical drive or oxidized SATA/power cable contacts can cause the issue. Try to disconnect your optical drive. If it helps try to connect/disconnect the cables to the optical drive 10-20 times in a row.