# Windows sometimes fails to resume from hibernate

Tags: windows-8.1, hibernate, dell-latitude

I have a Dell Latitude E5540 running Windows 8.1. Sometimes when I turn on my computer after hibernation it will completely restart Windows instead of resuming from hibernation.

When that happens I notice these entries in the System event log that indicate something went wrong when hibernating:

- **The previous system shutdown at *time* on ‎*date* was unexpected.**
- **The last shutdown's success status was false. The last boot's success status was true.**
- **Windows failed to resume from hibernate with error status 0xC0000411.**

What could the problem be and how can I solve it? Are there other steps I should take that would help me diagnose this further?

**More details...**

What I've tried so far but has not helped:

- My BIOS, Dell drivers, and Windows Update are all up to date.
- I turned off fast startup in Power Options. I read in a couple of threads that this option can cause problems with resuming from hibernation.
- I read that the graphics driver may cause this problem but there's not enough info on what to do about it. Should I uninstall the driver? Install another driver? Are there downsides?
- I tried changing the boot sequence because I read somewhere that could interfere with hibernation. My options for boot sequence are UEFI and Windows Boot Manager. I have tried different orders of these options and the problem has not gone away. (I have a feeling there are more boot sequence options but I cannot find them. I was expecting to see options for the DVD drive, USB, hard drive...)
- I disabled hibernation, ran defrag, and re-enabled hibernation.
- I read a comment somewhere suggesting disabling Intel Rapid Start but I cannot find such an option.
- I even sent the darn thing to Dell. They replaced some parts and *now the problem occurs even more frequently!*

Some other info about my system that may help:

- My bios is A10.
- Boot mode is set to UEFI, secure boot on.
- Graphics driver is Intel HD Graphics 4400 driver version 10.18.10.3574

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at this site; http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/windows-7-your-computer-cannot-come-out-of/20ffb7a3-7f0c-46f9-8516-c1e31b11e558?auth=1

I hope this helps

Comment: This answer, even if right, fails if the link dies. Would you copy the relevant part Of the site into this and cite it?

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: 1) Disable Hibernation.
2) Delete the hiberfil.sys file.
3) Reboot the computer and run 'Disk Cleanup.'
4) Defragment the drive.
5) Reboot one more time.
6) Reenable Hibernation.

Answer (score -3):

Dells are famous for things like this one. So, I found that updating your drivers will always help. http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/Products/laptop?app=drivers

Comment: He mentioned his drivers are already up to date.

Comment: I thought my drivers were up to date (according to Dell Command Update) but the scan at that link found a couple of more updates. However they still did not fix my problem.

Comment: "Dells are famous for things like this." Can you provide any citation?